# How to set the our own font to equation?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations, luatex, fontspec

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hiresbb]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathastext}


\newcommand{\lt}{<}
\newcommand{\hyphen}{\hyp}
\newcommand{\gt}{>}

\setmainfont[
 Path = /var/www/html/phplatex/Font/,
 Extension  = .ttf,
 Ligatures  = TeX,
 BoldFont   = timesbd,
 ItalicFont = timesi,
 BoldItalicFont = timesbi
]{timesbi}

\pagestyle{empty}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}
\newlength{\mydepth}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt} \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}

\fontsize{20pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
      $$f(x) = ax_2 + bx + c$$
\end{lrbox}

\settowidth {\mywidth}  {\usebox{\mybox}} \settoheight{\myheight}
{\usebox{\mybox}} \settodepth {\mydepth}  {\usebox{\mybox}}

\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname.sizes
    \immediate\write\foo{"Depth" : "\the\mydepth",}
    \immediate\write\foo{"Height" : "\the\myheight",}
    \addtolength{\myheight} {\mydepth}
    \immediate\write\foo{"TotalHeight" : "\the\myheight",}
    \immediate\write\foo{"Width" : "\the\mywidth"}
\closeout\foo

\begin{document}
    \color[rgb]{0,0,0}
    \pagecolor[rgb]{1,1,1}
    \usebox{\mybox}
\end{document}
```

When I use single `$` in the equation font doesn't applies, but if `$$` is used, then font is applied for the equation but not perfectly.

here is the output for the tex : 
[image]

1. Why font doesn't applied for the inline equation?
2. why font doesn't applied after the subscript in display equation?

Comment: Your example is not compilable.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE I'm afraid your code isn't compilable one has ttf font files located in a directory named `/var/www/html/_exeter/phplatex/Font/`. Please consider making your code (more) compilable by readers of your posting. Incidentally, does `timesbi` refer to a Times New Roman ***bold italic*** font?

Comment: Which operating system does your computer use? (The path `/var/www/html/phplatex/Font/` is not set up by default under MacOS 10.12 "Sierra".) By the way, the fact that you use the `mathastext` package fully answers both of your questions.

Comment: i'm using ubunthu.

Comment: Please use LuaLatex or xelatex to compile the code

Comment: Have you tried using `unicode-math` package? It perfectly fits your goal

Comment: @jagannathanjothi - Even if one uses XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX rather than pdfLaTeX, your code is not compilable on most (nearly all?!) computer systems and TeX distributions.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann - Does the suggestion contained in your comment help address the OP's two questions?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann In unicode-math package can i load my own fonts like cambria, times etc..

Comment: Yes, you surely can. I am not able to show it right now, but you can find a lot of examples on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I tried like this \usepackage{unicode-math} \setmathfont{/var/www/html/phplatex/Font/timesbd.ttf}
But it doesn't work

Comment: Please tell us what your are trying to achieve by setting the main document font to ***Times New Roman Bold Italic***. Is your objective to have bold-italic maths rather than (ordinary) italic maths? If so, you may want to (a) load the `bm` package, (b) *not* load the `mathastext` package, (c) not encase the equation in an `lrbox` environment, and (d) write (say) `$\bm{f(x) = ax_2 + bx + c}$`.

Comment: I am trying to set my own font to the equation.
For example If i set cambria, cambria font applied before the subscript. after the subscript it dosn't cambria font dosn't applied.

Comment: If you remove the subscript then the font is applied for the $$f(x) = ax2 + bx + c$$ for the equation

Comment: @MichaelFreimann can u pls send me the sample?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Could you add an answer to this question?